# Myopia (nearsightedness) in 1 year old toddler

Tags: toddler, infant, eyes

My 11-month-old baby girl was found to have extremely high myopia (-15.00, -13.00). I was wondering if anyone in this community has the similar experience. There is not enough information about myopia in infants. we completely have no idea what to do.

Some people who responded to this post ([Myopia in my 2 year old toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8420/myopia-in-my-2-year-old-toddler)) seem to have the similar experience, but I don't know how to get in touch with them. If any of you know them, would you please introduce me to them.

I don't have enough "reputation", I could not comment on that post.

Comment: Hi and welcome. We can't "get (you) in touch" with those users, but I'd be happy to direct them to this post. It's an old post, however. I hope that helps.

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: The information about infantile myopia is limited. I really want to know about their experience in dealing with this situation. Also, how are their children now? What kind of treatment did they receive, etc.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks  anongoodnurse

Comment: Hello and welcome! You could also edit your question (or ask separate ones) to make them answerable. Sadly there is no private message system on this site, but we have public chat rooms and sometime users connect there. Good Luck!

Comment: Hello MZ! I wrote one of the answers in the linked question and I was informed of your post. Not sure what I can contribute to you, except to say that my son's eyesight (discussed in that other post) turned out fine (it's been six years since that post) and that he doesn't need glasses now.

Answer (score 3):

My daughter had retinopathy of prematurity due to being born almost 3 months early. She had laser surgery and has worn glasses her entire life. She's now 15 and doing fine eye-wise. She gets eye exams yearly now same as we do, and her prescription barely changes.

Mostly it's not any different than anyone else wearing glasses. It's just more important to consistently wear her glasses as an infant so her vision will develop correctly. That's kind of hard to do, as she will want to pull them off, but just keep replacing them, and she will eventually relent.

Most new parents don't really anticipate making medical decisions early on. Know that you are more than capable of rising to the occasion and making appropriate adjustments. If you feel like you don't have enough information, keep asking your doctors questions until you do.

That's about as much as I can convey experience-wise, not knowing how similar your situation is to ours. My daughter has other more severe conditions, so I can't really comment on how her eyesight specifically affected her development. If you discovered the myopia because of developmental delays, there's a good chance she will eventually catch up now that you know what the problem is.

I would recommend seeing an opthamologist if you haven't already, especially if you still have unanswered concerns. They have more medical training than optometrists, and are more aware of connections with other medical conditions.

Comment: Thank you Karl. We are still trying to process our feelings and waiting for more tests to be done. The not knowing of the causes and her future really terrifies me. She was born full-term. She did not show any signs and was doing everything that she was supposed to do at her age. We went to see an ophthalmologist for her eye exam simply because our insurance would cover 100%. When we heard the bad news, we went to see a second ophthalmologist, we got the same result. We will meet a pediatric doctor tomorrow to see if we can do some genetic testing for Stickler syndrome.

Comment: I was born 3 months early, and had ROP (retinopathy of prematurity). I had to wear eyeglasses from 18 months. I was so young that they had to be tied on my head with a ribbon. I do not know if they were responsible, but I could read before I was 4.